# Detect first data binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, css-animations

I have the following attribute on a ng-repeat item template...

```
ng-class='$first ? "newItem" : ""'
```

This works great when I add a new item to my model with the click of a button. But I don't want the first item in the list to animate when the page first loads.

So how can I have the `newItem` class applied to the first element *only* when its a newly added element to the model?

Comment: you can just save a variable if the list was empty when loeaded `wasEmpty = myArray.lenght == 0` then you can `ng-class='$first && wasEmpty ? "newItem" : ""'`

Comment: Ahh... the list is not empty when it loads.

Comment: Perhaps a second class, without the animations, would be the best approach here.

Comment: How do you know when to use which class?

Comment: @IanWarburton i know, if you try that it will only animate if both conditions are true, is first and wasEmpty if I unesrtood your question thats what you needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the module [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate).
When you load it is not initialized, and only when you add a new item.

```js
angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate'])
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.items = [1, 2, 3];
        $scope.add = function() {
            $scope.items.push($scope.items.length + 1);
        };
    }]);
```

```css
.item.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
.item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="MainController">
    <button ng-click="add()">Add item</button>
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. That's a great answer.